# How to open url in React Native on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

How do you open a browser with an URL in a React Native app? I tried this using Linking, but nothing happens for me. Am I missing some other configuration?

```
<Button title="Open URL" onPress={() => { Linking.openURL("https://www.google.com") }}></Button>
```

Comment: Yes, this should work. I have just tried your posted snippet and it works for me on iOS. Is there an error message? Maybe your component does something that prevents it? Some wrong import maybe?

Comment: have you import the Linking from react-native?   `import { Button, Linking} from 'react-native';`